# Is there a way to pass helpful error messaging from contract to web3?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

Does anyone know if there is way to pass helpful error messages from a contract to web3? For example:

```
require(value > balance); // would be great if second arg was message
```

When testing with truffle I only get `VM Exception while processing transaction: revert`

I guess something I could do is to pass a uid to my function from the client thats created right before the call and emit an event with helpful messages and match uid's? for example:

```
event ErrorMessage(bytes32 uid, string msg);  

function doSomething (uint value, bytes32 uid) {
    if(value > balance) {
        ErrorMessage(uid, 'SomeErrorCode');
        revert();
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to find a good link now, but I believe a parameter for `revert` (and second parameter for `require`) are being discussed. I think it's likely this will get implemented, but I have no idea when.

Comment: Emitting an event won't have any effect if the transaction gets reverted. If you want to do something like this, you have to _not_ revert the transaction.

Comment: @smarx well I definitely want to revert. Maybe I will just stick to require and handle general errors

Comment: I think that's the best option for right now.

Answer (score 1):

Since solidity 0.4.22 you can put an error message in the require as a second argument.
https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.22

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Test {
        bytes32 name; // to check consumed gas

        function go() public {
            name = 'this is a test';
            require(false, "Error in script");
            name = 'another test';
        }

}
```

Comment: Use 0.4.23, it has some bug fixes of 0.4.22.

Comment: You can't get the error in web3 as of now.